# Oracle help on syntax error ORA-00907

Tags: sql, oracle

When I am trying to run code which is similar to the below one, Iam getting ORA-00907: missing right paranthesis error. Seems I have closed all paranthesis correctly.

Can anyone please help me out with this. Thanks

```
    with cte_tab1 as (
    select 
    tab1.*, 
  case
      when count(distinct Tab1.col_type) over (partition by Tab1.co_new) >1 
        then T_CDR.sales - nvl(T_CDR.profit,0) - nvl(T_CDR.proinf,0) 
      else 0 
  end as rsec_col
  from    tab1
   ),
CV as (
 select
case 
        when tab1.pro_cat in ('RP', 'DE', 'OT', 'CD')          
          then 'TC'
        when tab1.mew = 'TD' and tab1.d_type <> 'BS'
          then 'PREM' 
        else 'TC'
      end as bsspl_new,
sum(nvl(tab1.sales,0)) as gross_sal,
sum(tab1.rsec_col) as seccol
from cte_tab1 as tab1
group by 
case 
        when tab1.pro_cat in ('RP', 'DE', 'OT', 'CD')          
          then 'TC'
        when tab1.mew = 'TD' and tab1.d_type <> 'BS'
          then 'PREM' 
        else 'TC'
      end 
)
select cv.bsspl_new,
cv.gross_sal as gsl,
cv.seccol as ssl
from cv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> from cte_tab1 as tab1

`AS` **keyword** is not supported for **table aliasing** in Oracle. Remove it and you won't get the error.

Modify it to:

```
from cte_tab1 tab1
```

Comment: @SAIar Please mark it as answered, would help others too!